# Is 'userspace virtual filesystem - backends' necessary during installation of Gimp?

Tags: gimp

Because this add-on is selected by default in the Software Center. What it actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package in question is `gvfs-backends`. This is used by Gnome for various tasks--mounting remote and local resources in a way that any program can mount them. Due to the way the backend functions, these locations and resources can be mounted by non-root users. However, this package is not a dependency. It is only suggested, as per http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gimp. You can safely install GIMP via the terminal without installing `gvfs-backends` by

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

since `apt-get` does not install suggests. If you want to also skip recommends(not recommended if you want PDF, PS, and ghostscript support), you can install with:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp --no-install-recommends
```